# Other places for help when off-topic (or not clearly on-topic) for GIS SE?

Tags: discussion, faq

**I have a question that may be off topic (or not clearly on-topic) for this site, but it's still loosely related to GIS, so where can I go for help?**

List one site/resource/location per answer and describe the kind of support one is likely to find there.

This Q&A is:

- a Community Wiki, so edit to improve the existing answers, in preference to adding comments.
- linked to from our [Help > Asking page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so we need it to be comprehensive and current.

Alphabetical list of links to answers about alternative SE sites:

- [code debugging (when not spatial)](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/403/115)
- [code reviews](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/451/115)
- [databases, server setup, web services, etc](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/402/115)
- [hardware recommendations](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4389/115)
- [open data](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4376/115)
- [software recommendations](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4388/115)
- [web applications](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/427/115)
- [web hosting, cloud-based solutions, etc](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/405/115)

For a list of all sites within the Stack Exchange network, see the [Stack Exchange Sites Directory](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Answer (score 11):

For questions about **writing code that is NOT specific to a spatial library** consider researching/asking at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) which:

> is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code
>   because they love it.

For example, questions about writing code with:

- ArcPy, PyQGIS, ArcObjects, shapely, ArcGIS API for JavaScript, etc are on-topic for GIS SE
- Python, JavaScript, C#, etc, and which do not need a spatial library to be illustrated in a code snippet, are off-topic at GIS SE and should be researched/asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead

Some Meta GIS Q&As that lead to this position are:

- [Where is the line between Python and GIS?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/where-is-the-line-between-python-and-gis)
- [Handling overlap with Stack Overflow?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-handle-overlap-with-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 9):

**[Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)** should be used for questions relating to web hosting, cloud-based solutions, and things which generally reside on the web.

Answer (score 8):

**[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)** - general questions on databases, server setup, web services, etc. in a professional environment

Answer (score 5):

[**Web Applications Stack Exchange**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is a "...community driven Q&A for power users of web applications...".

I had [Online/cloud storage options for GIS file-based data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8553) closed on me here on GIS SE, was told to look on the [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), and I agreed.

Answer (score 5):

**[CartoTalk](http://www.cartotalk.com/)**, a "Forum for Cartography and Design". Many cartographers follow the community and it can be a nice place to get a cartographic review when looking to improve map designs.

Answer (score 3):

The **[Grass Developer Community](https://grass.osgeo.org/contribute/development/)** is a resource for people developing or modifying the GRASS software itself.

Here, on the GIS.SE site, we welcome--and usually quickly answer--questions about *using* and *applying* GRASS.

Answer (score 3):

The **[GDAL-DEV mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/listinfo/gdal-dev)** is also very active and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For questions about **open data**, even when it is open spatial data, consider researching/asking at the [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) which:

> is a Q&A site for developers, researchers, and anyone else interested
>   in open data.
>
> Open data, as defined by the [Open Definition](http://opendefinition.org/), is *any kind of data that
>   can be freely used, modified, and shared by anyone for any purpose*.

Users of the GIS Stack Exchange seem split on whether such questions are more on-topic at the [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) or here:

- [Migrating questions about obtaining open spatial data from GIS to Open Data?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/migrating-questions-about-obtaining-open-spatial-data-from-gis-to-open-data)

Answer (score 2):

Questions seeking **code reviews**, even when they are about spatial software, should be researched/asked at the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) which:

> is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.

Users of the GIS Stack Exchange seem to prefer that code review questions, even if they are about spatial code, are not asked here:

- [Code review for a specific piece of code](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317) (answered by @JeffAtwood)
- [Where can we ask code review questions for GIS related code?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4304)

---

@KirkKuykendall posted a [question on CodeReview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/can-i-use-imapdocument-in-a-10-1-soe). He did not have enough rep to tag it with an ArcObjects tag, so he posted a [feature-request](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/why-cant-rep-from-other-se-sites-count-towards-at-least-some-rep-here) on meta.codereview.

Answer (score 2):

For questions seeking **software recommendations**, even when they are about spatial software, consider researching/asking at the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) which:

> is a question and answer site for people seeking specific software
>   recommendations.
>
> Good software recommendation requests have two components: a purpose
>   (a task to accomplish, a user story) and some objective requirements
>   (a minimum set of features). Please read our [question quality
>   guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336) before asking for a recommendation.
>
> We request that answers demonstrate how the recommended product meets
>   the requirement and is suitable for the intended purpose. Please read
>   our [answer quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) before answering a question.

Users of the GIS Stack Exchange seem open to such questions continuing to be asked here ([Should questions asking for product, service, data and learning (course, book, website) recommendations be closed?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3660)) even though many Stack Exchange sites have made them explicitly off-topic, and a procedure to encompass that view has been developed ([Are software recommendations good candidates for being wiki locked?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4380)).

If you wish to ask for spatial software recommendations here, then please observe the same quality standards that the software recommendations experts have developed for [asking](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336) and [answering](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) them on the site that specializes in them.

Answer (score 1):

For questions seeking **hardware recommendations**, even when they are about hardware related to spatial topics, consider researching/asking at the [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) which:

> is a question and answer site for people seeking specific hardware
>   recommendations (what counts as "hardware" is set out in [What is
>   Hardware?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware))

Users of the GIS Stack Exchange seem open to such questions continuing to be asked here ([Should questions asking for product, service, data and learning (course, book, website) recommendations be closed?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3660)) even though many Stack Exchange sites have made them explicitly off-topic.

If you wish to ask for spatial hardware recommendations here, then please observe the same [quality guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality/206#206) that the hardware recommendations experts have developed.

Answer (score 0):

The **[gvSIG archives](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gvSIG-project-f4102529.html)** on Nabble "group the mailing lists of the gvSIG project."