# Links between SE sites

Tags: feature-request

In [my comment](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/311/4202) on meta.codereview, about the validity of having an `arcobjects` tag, I linked back to [this question](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/other-places-for-help) on meta.gis.

I was expecting this link to show up on the `Linked` sidebar on the meta.gis site, but it doesn't.

Maybe this is by design.  If so, then consider this a feature request.  A lot of GIS questions fall more in the code review category, yet posting there for the first time is not very productive - a user lacks sufficient rep to create a new tag.  This leaves tag decisions to members of the other site who have little familiarity with the tag in question.  Defining boundaries between different sites really would benefit from having cross-site links appear under the `Linked` sidebar.

Edit: I've made this bug more general.  This [question on codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/can-i-use-imapdocument-in-a-10-1-soe) links to [this question on gis.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/is-accessing-an-mxd-from-an-msd-based-soe-safe) and vice versa, but there's no mention of it in the `Linked` sidebar.

Comment: workaround - the user with insufficient rep can leave a comment for the tag to be included by a member with more than sufficient rep.

Comment: @mapperz  I'll be starting a new thread later for moving questions between SE sites.  For now I thought I'd just focus on what I consider a bug that makes that activity less productive.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable suggestion (see also [this post on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/also-display-other-se-site-links-as-linked-questions)), but I'm curious as to how you think it would help when it comes to migration - could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: @Shog9 I'm reluctant to tell someone to post their GIS code problem on CodeReview if it won't get much visibility.  Visiblity requires tags, which require discussion on both meta sites.  Then once they are there, the actual question about the code may likely reference contexts in GIS where the code might be used.  Without links in the sidebar it will be hard to find the context.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're thinking of?

[Display other SE site links in the linked questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/also-display-other-se-site-links-as-linked-questions)

If so, that might be worth supporting.

Comment: Yes, that'll work, thanks!