# Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers?

Tags: support, status-completed, faq, duplicate-questions, unanswered-questions

I have a question that has already been asked ([Understanding min and max values with Mosaic to New Raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137940/mosaic-to-new-raster-problem-with-min-and-max-values)), but it does not yet have an answer.

Is there a way to revive or draw attention to this question, or any question with no, inadequate or old answers, in order to get the question answered or its answers improved/refreshed, irrespective of whether they have been accepted or not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Seven ways to help revive/refresh a question (including closed questions), and its answers are by:

1. using the **share** button beneath the question to advertise it to your networks (no rep needed)
2. suggesting an edit to improve it that then gets approved i.e. provide additional details or clarify existing details (no rep needed)
3. raising the need for more editors/voters/etc by asking how to get its profile raised by asking here in Meta SE.  However, if you choose this one you will need to make a good case why, in order to avoid downvoting. (needs [Participate in Meta](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege that comes with rep of 5+)
4. adding upvotes to it (needs the [Vote Up](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) privilege that comes with a rep of 15+)
5. drawing attention to it in the [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) (needs [Talk in Chat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) privilege that comes with rep of 20+)
6. [offering a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) (costs minimum of 50 points of rep)
7. editing to improve it immediately i.e. provide additional details or clarify existing details (needs [Edit Questions and Answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege that comes with rep of 2,000+)

In the case of the question you linked to I offered a bounty of 50 points (the minimum) and within an hour or so the question now has an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/158794).  Whether or not that answer is ever accepted (which can only be done by the asker of the question) is not as important as whether it starts to accumulate upvotes to indicate its quality.

As someone with low reputation (6) at the moment, only the first three options are available to you, so I hope the value of earning reputation has become apparent.  Once 50 rep points no longer seems a lot to give away, it makes drawing attention to questions you want answered easy to do.

---

Our help page at https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers provides similar advice.

The one thing that you **should NOT do is to ask the same question again** because it is likely to be quickly closed as a duplicate, and may attract downvotes which can place some of the options listed above out of reach.

---

Not all questions are suitable for the focused Q&A format of GIS SE. See [Other places for help when off-topic (or not clearly on-topic) for GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401)